# How to execute shell script on Kali Linux startup?

Tags: linux, shell-script, kali-linux, startup, gdm3

I need to execute a shell script on a Kali Linux startup. I am using 2016.1 version of Kali Linux.

i tried many things like `rc.local`, `init.d`, X11 and GDM3 config etc.
 but I couldn't get it work.

This is the shell script that I want to execute:

```
#!/bin/bash

xrandr --newmode 1366x768 85.500 1366 1494 1624 1798 768 770 776 795 +hsync -vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1366x768
xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode 1366x768
```

Comment: anyone here? need a big help!

Comment: Is the file executable? Can you run it from an interactive shell? What did you try wth your different approaches (which files did you edit how)?

Comment: can you place the script in `/etc/profile.d/` ? Any script in that directory should run when you log in. Or maybe put it in `/etc/bashrc` ?

Answer (score 3):

You can add an item in `~/.config/autostart`,

e.g Open `~/.config/autostart/myscript.desktop`, and paste the following contents

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=MyScript
GenericName=A descriptive name
Comment=Some description about your script
Exec=/path/to/my/script.sh
Terminal=false
Type=Application
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

And make sure the script is executable.

Comment: Debain based Kali Linux doesn't have an `~/.config/autostart` path...

Comment: @ChathulaSampathPerera it has nothing to do with debian. Try create that folder

Answer (score 1):

Try crontab --help and use

@reboot 
:EXAMPLE: @reboot macchanger -r eth0
 (I got this from a video so im giving credit where credit is due)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OcVE6rQ9_FU
04:38:57

Answer (score 0):

I see you're attempting to force a custom resolution in your monitor in every boot.

I have not used Kali Linux myself, but I'm willing to guess you could add the commands to an **.xprofile** file in your home directory, as most display managers would run the content of the file when initializing.

If you don't have this file in your home directory, just create it, paste your commands in it, save it and reboot. You can see more about this in [this article from the ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xprofile).